# Parsing body in node js results in 'First argument must be a string or Buffer'

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a phaser game that's supposed to send player data to the server, for verification. Here's my code for that:

```
postUserInfo(callback, context, loader, data) {
    let body = `prefix=${data.prefix}&prefix_id=${data.prefix_id}&suffix=${data.suffix}&suffix_id=${data.suffix_d}&password=${data.password}`;
    const realUrl = this.url + 'saveUserInfo';
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', realUrl, true);
    xhr.timeout = this.timeout;
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 201) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                var jsonValue = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                loader.style.display = 'none';
                callback(jsonValue.message);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(body);
}
```

And here's my server-side code, based from [this](https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-the-post-request-body-in-node-js-without-using-a-framework-cd2038b93190):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const { parse } = require('querystring');
app.post('/saveUserInfo', function (req, res) {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        let data = parse(body)
        console.log(data);
        res.end(data);
    });    
});
```

I'm just trying to pass the data with as little external modules or body-parsers as possible, because this is just a small problem I need to fix before tackling a bigger issue - testing database insertion and putting the code on AWS Lambda (where I assume some of these won't work).

However, even this has stumped me.

If the game posts, this is the response of the server (before crashing):

```
{ prefix: 'shy',
  prefix_id: 'undefined',
  suffix: 'ant',
  suffix_id: 'undefined',
  pin: 'undefined' }
_http_outgoing.js:558
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^
```

Postman on the other hand, seems to post a wildly different data, with the same result:

```
{ '----------------------------117273776358694001644449\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"prefix"\r\n\r\nsmall\r\n----------
------------------117273776358694001644449\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="prefixID"\r\n\r\n2\r\n----------------------------
117273776358694001644449\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="suffix"\r\n\r\nkangaroo\r\n----------------------------1172737763586
94001644449\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="suffixID"\r\n\r\n10\r\n----------------------------117273776358694001644449--\r\n
' }
_http_outgoing.js:558
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^
```

[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong? It seems so straight forward in the example.

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to `res.end(data);` where you are passing it an object when it only takes a string or a buffer.

You need to do `res.end(JSON.stringify(data));` for it to work.

Comment: That allowed the server to continue, and even sent out the data I wanted, but the browser logs the following error:

`XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://192.168.1.70:3031/saveUserInfo
Line Number 1, Column 1:`

Comment: If I had to guess that would be because you're not setting the Content-Type header on the response to indicate that it's a JSON payload. Your browser is expecting it to be some default type, which in this case seems to be XML.